# custom List view with lazy loading causes Index outof bound exception

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        OnClickListener {

private int mCount = 10;

// String mPositionString;

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

// int mTextViewResourceId;

public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // mPositionString = activity.getString(d.length) + " ";

    // mTextViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
    // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

public void addMoreItems(int count) {
    mCount += count;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getCount() {

    return mCount;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// @Override
// public int getViewTypeCount() {
// return 2;
// }

/********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView textWide;
    public ImageView image;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

        /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.text.setText("Company " + position);
    holder.text1.setText("company description " + position);
    ImageView image = holder.image;

    // DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);

    /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
    vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MainActivity sct = (MainActivity) activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
    }
}
```

}

> at  >>>    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
>    the error is

[image]

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {

```
ListView list;
LazyImageLoadAdapter mAdapter;

private final int AUTOLOAD_THRESHOLD = 4;
private final int MAXIMUM_ITEMS = 1052;

private View mFooterView;
private Handler mHandler;
private boolean mIsLoading = false;
private boolean mMoreDataAvailable = true;
private boolean mWasLoading = false;


private Runnable mAddItemsRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.addMoreItems(10);
        mIsLoading = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Create custom adapter for listview
    mAdapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(this, mStrings);

    // Set adapter to listview

    // Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // b.setOnClickListener(listener);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    // mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
    // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    mFooterView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.loading_view,
            null);
    list.addFooterView(mFooterView, null, false);
    // LIST(MADAPTER);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    list.setOnScrollListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Remove adapter refference from list
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // Refresh cache directory downloaded images
        mAdapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    String tempValues = mStrings[mPosition];

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image URL : " + tempValues,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

// Image urls used in LazyImageLoadAdapter.java file

private String[] mStrings = {
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
        "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png"

};

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (!mIsLoading && mMoreDataAvailable) {
        if (totalItemCount >= MAXIMUM_ITEMS) {
            mMoreDataAvailable = false;
            list.removeFooterView(mFooterView);
        } else if (totalItemCount - AUTOLOAD_THRESHOLD <= firstVisibleItem
                + visibleItemCount) {
            mIsLoading = true;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mAddItemsRunnable, 1000);

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Ignore
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mWasLoading) {
        mWasLoading = false;
        mIsLoading = true;
        mHandler.postDelayed(mAddItemsRunnable, 1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAddItemsRunnable);
    mWasLoading = mIsLoading;
    mIsLoading = false;
}
```

}

this is my MainActivity class using OnScrollListener for data showing after scrolling .

and this is exception

please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `data` array does not contain the same amount of values as your `mCount` variable tells the adapter. Try to fix this issue the following way:

```
// change your method implementation that returns mCount to this one
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}
```

This is supposed to fix the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that you are getting. The next step for you, I guess, would be implementation of `addMoreItems` method so that it would add items to your array, and not just update the counter.

**Edit**

If you manually update `mCount`, consider the following code:

```
public void addMoreItems(int count) {
    // update the counter
    mCount += count;
    // if now your counter exceeds the size of the array,
    // set its value to the size
    if (mCount >= data.length) {
        mCount = data.length;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also, just to make sure, you should check if you are trying to access your array at the index that is the same as its size: `data[mCount]` may be wrong, if `mCount` equals to the size of your array, in that case you should use `data[mCount - 1]` instead.

Comment: This shows all list data at once but here im using a addMoreItems method for 10 item at once to show in list and after onScroll listner